# Custom Loggingwithout Contsructor DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection

How can i log custom Information/Error based on providers registered without constructor dependecy injection in each class? (beacsue i have single controller mutiple repos called inside controller and i cannot alter the repo i,e class constructor)

Eg i want to log information in below context without touching controller constrcutor

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            base.OnException(context);
            var logger = Dependency.Resolve<ILogger>();
            **//var logger = getIloggerSomehow from startup regsistred loggers**

            logger.LogInformation("Custom Info");

        }
```

My Startup services is looks below and it writes dotnet and Microosft logs everywhere i expect.
How can i write custom log at all these places?

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
              {
                    loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));                    loggingBuilder.AddAWSProvider(Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection());
                loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
                loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            });
```

Comment: Why? This hard-codes the reference to the DI container, *exactly* what `ILogger` is meant to prevent. Instead of depending on just the logging library, you'd now depend on the logging library *and* the specific DI library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks. 
 otherwise how can i add the custom logging here whihc will be distributed to all providers

Comment: You could use [a singleton LoggingFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#non-host-console-app) and use it to create loggers as needed, or even create a singleton logger. This way you avoid taking a dependency on a DI container. Again `why` matters

Comment: `how can i add the custom logging here whihc will be distributed to all providers` by configuring logging inside `AddLogging`. Constructor injection makes this *easier*, not harder - injection doesn't affect how logging works, but you *don't* have to look into multiple places to create your logger, nor do you have to worry about missing a logger field. What does that phrase mean though? What kind of custom logging do you mean?

Comment: Basically i need global log object with which i can log.LogInformation() through out applications

Comment: `i need global log object with which i can log.LogInformation() through out applications –` no you don't. That's why that instance is injected in the constructor instead of having a singleton. Again, you can create a singleton if you want, but that makes logging harder to use for the rest of your code - and **definitely** a lot harder to test

Comment: I suspect the *real* question is how to make `ILogger` behave the same way as whatever logging library you used in previous projects? Perhaps Serilog, which does use a global logger?

Comment: [Check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#non-host-console-app) that show how to use ILogger without a host. You can create your own logger instance or logger factory and store it in a static property of, eg, a `Log` class. You could even create that logger in your `Main()` method and store it in a static property, making this a singleton.

Comment: Once you do that though, you'll have to ensure that property is set in *every* unit test of your application, otherwise your code will throw a NullReferenceException. You'll *always* forget to do so in at least one test (guess how I know). With constructor injection, the compiler itself will prevent this bug. You can pass a [NullLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nulllogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in unit tests when you don't really need logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve the service from the `context` in the `OnException` method:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
...
var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<YourFilter>>();
```

Comment: var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger>(); is always null

Comment: How did you register `ILogger` then?

Comment: Or are you trying to resolve an `ILogger<T>`? Just replace `T` with the type of the filter then. See my edit.

Comment: i have registered Ilogger sa below


services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {

                loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                loggingBuilder.AddAWSProvider(Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection());
                loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
                loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            });

Comment: Did you try `context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<YourClass>>();`?

Comment: Thanks a lot when i replace "YourClass" in above sinppet with any class in project its working now..Thanks a lot..
But dynamic tyep is not working

context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<RecordRepo>>(); isowrking

where 

context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<context.GetType()>>(); 
is not

Thanks a lot anyway